# geom_segment variable length error

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code worked in `ggplot2` before I updated to version 2.2.0.  Now I get `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (30): x, y, xend, yend`.  The error is caused by the two `geom_segment` calls.

```
drug1 <- c(.7, -1.6, -.2, -1.2, -.1, 3.4, 3.7, .8, 0, 2)
drug2 <- c(1.9, .8, 1.1, .1, -.1, 4.4, 5.5, 1.6, 4.6, 3.4)
d <- data.frame(Drug=c(rep('Drug 1', 10), rep('Drug 2', 10),
                  rep('Difference', 10)),
                extra=c(drug1, drug2, drug2 - drug1))

ggplot(d, aes(x=Drug, y=extra)) + 
  geom_boxplot(col='lightyellow1', alpha=.3, width=.5) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position='dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", col='red', shape=18, size=5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=rep('Drug 1', 30), xend=rep('Drug 2', 30), y=drug1, yend=drug2),
               col=gray(.8)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x='Drug 1', xend='Difference', y=drug1, yend=drug2 - drug1),
               col=gray(.8)) +
  xlab('') + ylab('Extra Hours of Sleep') + coord_flip()
```

*Update*: Improved code that works:

```
drug1 <- c(.7, -1.6, -.2, -1.2, -.1, 3.4, 3.7, .8, 0, 2)
drug2 <- c(1.9, .8, 1.1, .1, -.1, 4.4, 5.5, 1.6, 4.6, 3.4)
d <- data.frame(Drug=c(rep('Drug 1', 10), rep('Drug 2', 10),
                  rep('Difference', 10)),
                extra=c(drug1, drug2, drug2 - drug1))
w <- data.frame(drug1, drug2, diff=drug2 - drug1)

ggplot(d, aes(x=Drug, y=extra)) +
  geom_boxplot(col='lightyellow1', alpha=.3, width=.5) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position='dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", col='red', shape=18, size=5) +
  geom_segment(data=w, aes(x='Drug 1', xend='Drug 2', y=drug1, yend=drug2),
               col=gray(.8)) +
  geom_segment(data=w, aes(x='Drug 1', xend='Difference', y=drug1, yend=drug2 - drug1),
               col=gray(.8)) +
  xlab('') + ylab('Extra Hours of Sleep') + coord_flip()
```

Comment: Your `drug1` and `drug2` are both length 10 . try `y=rep(drug1, 3)` and `yend=rep(drug2, 3))` (I also think it would be nicer to add these to a second data frame rather than leaving ggplot to look in the global env)

Comment: Excellent.  I'm improving the code as you suggest, in the original posting.

Comment: @FrankHarrell so I understand the context, are `drug1` and `drug2` paired values (e.g. associated with the same subject)?

Comment: Correct, as in a crossover study.

Answer (score 1):

The updated version of the code produces a data-frame `d`, that looks like this:

```
drug1 <- c(.7, -1.6, -.2, -1.2, -.1, 3.4, 3.7, .8, 0, 2)
drug2 <- c(1.9, .8, 1.1, .1, -.1, 4.4, 5.5, 1.6, 4.6, 3.4)
d <- data.frame(Drug=c(rep('Drug 1', 10), rep('Drug 2', 10),
                  rep('Difference', 10)),
                extra=c(drug1, drug2, drug2 - drug1))

> d
         Drug extra
1      Drug 1   0.7
2      Drug 1  -1.6
3      Drug 1  -0.2
4      Drug 1  -1.2
5      Drug 1  -0.1
6      Drug 1   3.4
7      Drug 1   3.7
8      Drug 1   0.8
9      Drug 1   0.0
10     Drug 1   2.0
11     Drug 2   1.9
12     Drug 2   0.8
13     Drug 2   1.1
14     Drug 2   0.1
15     Drug 2  -0.1
16     Drug 2   4.4
17     Drug 2   5.5
18     Drug 2   1.6
19     Drug 2   4.6
20     Drug 2   3.4
21 Difference   1.2
22 Difference   2.4
23 Difference   1.3
24 Difference   1.3
25 Difference   0.0
26 Difference   1.0
27 Difference   1.8
28 Difference   0.8
29 Difference   4.6
30 Difference   1.4
```

This is a problematic way to create the data-frame for two reasons:

1. The variables `drug1` and `drug2` exist in both the global environment and within the data.frame `d`. This creates the potential for confusion, masking, and other errors.
2. The only way `Difference` is tied to the values that produced the difference is the row ordering. For instance, the values in row 1 and row 11 produced the difference in row 21. This can create problems if you do any later modification of the data set.

I would suggest creating the data-frame in a manner like this:

```
d2 <- data.frame(
  pair = 1:10,
  drug1 = c(.7, -1.6, -.2, -1.2, -.1, 3.4, 3.7, .8, 0, 2),
  drug2 = c(1.9, .8, 1.1, .1, -.1, 4.4, 5.5, 1.6, 4.6, 3.4)
) 

   pair drug1 drug2
1     1   0.7   1.9
2     2  -1.6   0.8
3     3  -0.2   1.1
4     4  -1.2   0.1
5     5  -0.1  -0.1
6     6   3.4   4.4
7     7   3.7   5.5
8     8   0.8   1.6
9     9   0.0   4.6
10   10   2.0   3.4
```

There is an explicit `pair` variable that links the values, and no extra copies of `drug1` and `drug2` exist outside of `d2`.

You can then use `tidyr` to convert to tidy/long format (for nice use with ggplot and modeling packages):

```
tidyr::gather(d2, drug, value, drug1, drug2)

   pair  drug value
1     1 drug1   0.7
2     2 drug1  -1.6
3     3 drug1  -0.2
4     4 drug1  -1.2
5     5 drug1  -0.1
6     6 drug1   3.4
7     7 drug1   3.7
8     8 drug1   0.8
9     9 drug1   0.0
10   10 drug1   2.0
11    1 drug2   1.9
12    2 drug2   0.8
13    3 drug2   1.1
14    4 drug2   0.1
15    5 drug2  -0.1
16    6 drug2   4.4
17    7 drug2   5.5
18    8 drug2   1.6
19    9 drug2   4.6
20   10 drug2   3.4
```

Comment: I see what you are getting at but that is a very long way to do it in my humble opinion.  A separate package should not be needed for this application.  I prefer the original but you are right it would be better to not have variables hanging around in the global environment.  The improved code I posted is not confused by these global variables though.

Comment: When I look at the updated section of your original post, the two issues still remain. Not having an explicit variable like `pair` could easily lead to problems.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on that point.  I don't need `pair` when I have direct access to the two paired measurements.